# Где валидировать user input?

Tags: java, spring, rest

Есть CRUD API к **Entity**. 
Entity имеет поля id и someString
Состоит из трех слоев : Controller, Service, Repository
Естественно контроллер знает только о сервисе, а сервис только о репозитории
Между клиентом и сервером jakson маршалит **Entity**(json).

в контроллере есть такие методы

```
Entity getById(@PathVariable Long id)
Entity create(@RequestBody Entity entity)
void delete(@PathVariable Long id)
Entity update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Entity entity)
```

аналогичные методы присутствуют и в сервисе

Используется **Spring Data** и соответственно **JpaRepository**.
как известно у нее по умолчанию нет метода **update**. И создание и обновление entity решаетcя с помощью метода save. Соответственно если мы передаем в метод **save** Entity с установленным ID то происходит обновление оного, в противном случае создается новая запись в БД.

А вопрос состоит вот в чем:

Где нужно валидировать Entity от клиента, залетающая в метод **create** контроллера, на присутствие id в ней дабы вместо создания записи не произошла правка уже существующей: в сервисе, в контроллере или самой модели.

Где нужно проверять наличие Entity в базе, залетающая в метод **update**, перед тем как апдейтить запись дабы не создать новую.

Answer (score 3):

Валидируйте в слое сервиса.

Если нет ограничения на количество запросов к базе, то сначала проверьте есть ли сущность с таким id. Если ограничение есть, то кешируйте id, немного сэкономите.

- Контроллер проводит манипуляции с вьюшками и сущностями, чтобы они подружились.
- Репозиторий делает тоже самое только с БД и сущностями.
- Т.е. для логических действий остается слой сервиса

Comment: А как же  быть тогда с тем что при create наличие в Entity id это не валидный ввод пользователя. получается что мы разсираем валиацию на два слоя?

Comment: Да. Это логично, потому что это 2 разные валидации. Сервис ничего не знает о клиенте, о клиенте знает контроллер. Поэтому контроллер проверяет все, что приходит от клиента и если клиент передал не то, что надо, контроллер его и разворачивает. Если все хорошо, отдает сервису и сервис проверяет то, что нужно ему (наличие в БД через репозиторий). Так же валидировать клиентские данные можно на самом клиенте, сэкономите на запросах.

Answer (score 3):

Это всё должно разруливаться на уровне контроллера, принимающего запрос и данные. Поясню, что имею ввиду: если мы хотим создать Entity, то выполняем запрос методом POST, если нам нужно изменить существующую Entity, то выполняем запрос методом PUT.

Валидировать данные нужно во-первх на клиенте (JavaScript), во-вторых на сервере (есть у спринга интерфейс Validator и аннотация @Validated).

В итоге имеем в контроллере такие методы

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
Entity create(@RequestBody @Validated Entity entity)

@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
Entity update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody @Validated Entity entity)
```

Comment: В дополнение хочу добавить что можно в анотацию Validated передать маркерный интерфейс например @Validated(New.class) в create, а @Validated(Update.class) в update соответственно, и в ДТО маркнуть поле id анотациями @Null(groups = {New.class}) и @NotNull(groups = {Update.class}), и тогда в разных методах контроллера валидация будет разная